# Get QuickAction name from Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

I have a Quick action button that calls a Lightning component. This works fine. The problem is a new button that performs a slightly different operation, but uses the same component layout.

So need to be able to determine the the Quick action button name from within the Lightning component.

When capturing web traffic you can see Quick Action API and label name being passed when the button is clicked - but I think this just tells SalesForce to show the component, don't think it gets passed to component:

```
"components": [
                {
                    "componentDef": {
                        "descriptor": "markup://forceChatter:lightningComponent"
                    },
                    "creationPath": "/*[0]",
                    "attributes": {
                        "values": {
                            "insideScroller": false,
                            "isWebApp": true,
                            "inPanel": false,
                            "publisherFeedType": "Record",
                            "enableLinkDetection": true,
                            "quickActionApiName": "**Opportunity.QuickActionName**",
```

But haven't been able to find the quick action name in the component.

Have tried the

```
{
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var params = event.getParams();
    console.log("All event parameters: ",JSON.stringify( params));
    console.log("PageRef " +  window.location.pathname);
```

I have looked at quickActionAPI - but this seems help getting information about calling actions from a component, not getting information about what was called.

There is a StackExchange question that talks about nesting component, but was hoping to avoid that.